# Error: array_key_exists() when creating new user in UserController in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, new-operator

I am trying to create new user in my UserController but getting error. can't find any help on google.

I tried to disable the validator and still getting same error.

```php
$user = User::create([
   'name' => $name,
   'phone' => $phone,
   'email' => $email,
   'password' => Hash::make($password),
   'gym' => $gym,
   'user_role' => $user_role,
   'active' => $active
]);
```

> "message": "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer",
>     "exception": "ErrorException",
>     "file":

Comment: adding the whole code of 'store()' function here would be helpful..

Comment: As @TharakaDilshan said, please post the whole store function.

Comment: And the full error stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

in my case error is in this line

```
    $attrs = Attribute::get();
    $attribute_ids = $attrs->map->only(['id']); // solved
```

instead of

```
    $attrs = Attribute::get();
    $attribute_ids = $attrs->get(['id']); // here was my error
```

i replace first

and the second not worked

> ```
> "message": "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer",
> "exception": "ErrorException",
> ```